# Failed to restore nuget packages on Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, nuget-package-restore

I am completely new to Docker. I am trying to learn how to dockerize .NET Core app based on [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/).

Whatever I do, I can't dockerize it. I am always stuck on:

```
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

within dockerfile.

Errors I get are:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   An
>   error occurred while sending the request. [C:\app\TokenGen.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :
>   The server name or address could not be resolved
>   [C:\app\TokenGen.csproj]

I noticed that he is pointing to

> C:\app

even tho my sample project is on

> H:\Bitbucket\dockertest\TokenGen

This is my full dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: Are you using docker for windows? If so you need to also share `H:\` in Docker daemon settings

Comment: Yes, I am using Docker for Windows. How can I share H partition in Docker daemon settings?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't have "Shared Drives". I only have: General, Proxies, Daemon, Diagnose & Feedback, Reset.

Comment: Not a windows user, so not sure why